# What is the use of team-provider-info.json?

Tags: aws-amplify

What is the use of `team-provider-info.json` file in AWS Amplify and should I commit it to version control?

What happens if I remove this file from version control?

I have multi-environment setup where 3 branches deploy to 3 environments. Will that be impacted if I remove `team-provider-info.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `team-provider-info.json` file allows multiple team members to share the same project cloud resources. For instance, all developers share the same dev environment resources in the same CloudFormation stack. They can push/provision resources in the same stack to be in sync with the latest state of resources.

Because this file includes information about your resources in your AWS account, you should not commit this to version control if your project is shared publicly. In that case, you would add it to the `.gitignore` file. In this case, people who clone your repo would create their own environments in their own AWS account.

While using multiple environments each with their own branch, the Amplify CLI needs the `team-provider-info.json` file so that it knows info about the environment and the resources in that environment. In this case, if you remove the file, the CLI will throw an error indicating the environment is invalid, the file doesn't exist, etc.

You can read more about this file here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/shared/#sharing-projects-outside-the-team